# Meaning of 3-disjoint

Tags: graph-theory, commutative-algebra, definition

**Definition:** Two edges $\{x, y\}$ and $\{w, z\}$ of $G$ are said to be **3-disjoint** if the induced subgraph of $G$ on $\{x, y, w, z\}$ consists of exactly two disjoint edges. (See page 5 of [this file](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0273v1.pdf).)

I understand the definition meaning but i do not understand why do we call 3-disjoint, and what is the meaning of 3-disjoint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the article](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/JACO/Volume27_2/58431851n2161011.fulltext.pdf) they borrow the term from, the authors use $t$-disjoint to mean the edges are at distance at least $t$.  Two edges in this particular graph $G$ that induce a subgraph of two disjoint edges are actually at distance at least $3$ (as opposed to $2$, as you might think), because the graph is bipartite.